# Were there Hungarian speaking Indians in South America?

Tags: history, anthropology, archaeology

The following story is a translation from Hungarian, with a lot of discussion in the blog's comments:

http://www.cakravartin.com/archives/south-american-natives-speak-ancient-european-language

The story in a nutshell:

> In the 1960s, a guy called János Móricz (Móricz János in Hungarian order) discovered Indians in South America that he could speak Hungarian with, because their native language was so similar. He concluded that Hungarians and these Indian tribes were one nation in the not so distant past. More recent DNA analysis confirms this. For some reason (conspiracy of world-domination-hungry Mormons) his discoveries never reached the general public, the press intentionally silenced him, academia refused him, etc. He also found a cave system spanning the entire Andes, containing an ancient metal plate library documenting the whole history of humankind, and the ancient cosmic secrets that are kept secret by some powers.

So how can we verify or disprove this?

Comment: Just for clarity, are you only asking about the Hungarian-speaking Indians, or do you wish us to investigate the metal plate library containing ancient cosmic secrets?

Comment: @DJClayworth I'm interested in both, but I think I should ask two questions then, is that right? I'm new to Skeptics.SE. (BTW how on earth can one attempt debunking these, or even obtaining any information other than from the supporters of the theory?)

Comment: Being in the same paragraph with "ancient cosmic secret", destroys any credibility the claim about hungarian-speaking amerindians could have had.

Comment: In case any Spanish speaker wants to answer this question, here is the original source for the claim https://www.scribd.com/doc/148783924/Juan-Moricz-El-Origen-Americano-de-Pueblos-Europeos

Comment: Magyar / mayan, this cannot be coincidence!

Comment: Isn't the last sentence enough?